# Overleaf logo command (like \LaTeX)

Tags: macros, overleaf, logos

I would like to make a command `\overleaf` which prints the Overleaf logo, just like `\LaTeX` prints the LaTeX logo. Here is a [\link to the Overleaf logo](https://www.overleaf.com/for/partners/logos). 
The link includes several examples of the logo and several formats, including SVG, PNG, EPS, and TIFF.

I presume it is necessary to use an image of the logo to make the command? However, I think it would be best if it has the same color as the text (If the text is red, the logo is red; if the text is black, the logo is black.)

Anyone who can help me get started?

Comment: This logo is very likely protected by copyright. So, you should be sure that you are allowed to use it. Apart from that, I would recommend that you convert a vectorised format of the logo (SVG or EPS) to TikZ, which you can then easily use in the context of LaTeX and with different colors.

Comment: just save the image, say `overleaf.png` then use `\includegraphics{overleaf}` you don't need anything other than teh graphicx package.

Comment: @JasperHabicht  I think the advice to convert to tikz is probably bad (for the reason that you start with)  the company provide svg logos with particular fonts and branding colours and licenced fro specific uses. If you convert them and modify the fonts and colours then you are almost certainly not using the logos as licenced (but as they say, i am not a lawyer)

Comment: I would not change the colours that green is part of the corporate branding but the page you link to has a contact link, you coul dask them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are totally right. I was arguing primarily from a technical point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sent another e-mail asking if I could create a command for the logo in text (Overleaf, not just the O). This was the response I got (I also asked if I needed to use the branding colours, or if it was okay to make it the same color as the text):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I send Overleaf a message, asking them for such a command/ or permission to create one. This is the response: [image: Reply from Overleaf]

The example Dan send me was:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{url}
\title{academic icons}
\author{Dan (Overleaf Support) MacKinnon}
\date{November 2019}

\begin{document}


\maketitle


{\large \url{dan.mackinnon@overleaf.com} \aiOverleaf}

{\large \url{https://orcid.org/0000-0001-7049-6927} \aiOrcid}


\end{document}
```

Which yields:

[image: Result from code]

Comment: A very diligent answer!